# ¿como hacer que el boton puesto por appendChild() no se haga pequeño?

Tags: javascript, html

Buen dia comunidad, estoy presentando datos de una api en un html y usando javascript, sin embargo cuando pongo un boton con el metodo appendChild el boton me aparece bien pero cuando agrego un segundo boton con este método el primero se hace pequeño, adjunto una imagen con el problema. ¿Alguien sabe por qué pasa esto?.

```
            //agregando botones
            //CREANDO PRIMER BOTON
            const button = document.createElement('button'); 
            button.type = 'button'; 
            button.innerText = 'POSTS'; 
            document.getElementById('uno').appendChild(button);
            
            const button2 = document.createElement('button'); 
            button.type = 'button'; 
            button.innerText = 'JEJE'; 
            document.getElementById('uno').appendChild(button2);
            // var list = document.getElementById("uno");
            // list.insertBefore(button2, list.childNodes[0]);

            }
```

[image: imagen con boton pequeñp]

Comment: Es un error de tipeo, estas siempre estas usando `button` en lugar de `button2`